# program only executing first IF statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm currently having an issue where my program will only execute the first 
if statement, where it multiplies 'w' by 3.5, even if 'w' does not meet the requirements. If I put an input of 4, the output turns into 14 (4*3.5) where it should really be 34 (4*8.5) since the weight is between 3 and 10 lbs. I'm sure the fix is simple, but I can't seem to find it!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
float w, price;
cout << "Enter weight of package : ";
cin >> w;

if (0 < w <= 1)
{
    price = 3.5 * w;
}
else if (1 < w <= 3)
{
    price = 5.5 * w;
}
else if (3 < w <= 10)
{
    price = 8.5 * w;
}
else if (10 < w <= 20)
{
    price = 10.5 * w;
}
else if (20 < w <= 30)
{
    price = 12.5 * w;
}
else if (30 < w)
{
    cout << "The package cannot be shipped" << endl;
}
else
    cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
cout << "Weight : " << w << " lbs" << endl;
cout << "Shipping cost : $" << price << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have intended to use:

```
if (0 < w && w <= 1)
```

Instead of:

```
if (0 < w <= 1)
```

Your current approach (using your example where `w = 4`) evaluates like this:

```
if ((0 < 4) <= 1)
```

Which simplifies to:

```
if (1 <= 1)
```

Which evaluates to `true`.

According to the C++ standard (section 4.7, clause 4):

> If the source type is `bool`, the value `false` is converted to zero and
>   the value `true` is converted to one.

Comment: Ah I see! I had completely forgotten about using '&&', and how my approach would run wrong like you explained. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

`if(3<w<20)` is a wrong statement. You should have `if(3<w&&w<20)`.

Answer (score 2):

`a < w < b` doesn't produce the effect you expect, it actually evaluates to `(a < w) < b)`, where `a < b` will have a true/false value. I would suggest to rewrite your code like this:

```
if (w <= 0)
{
    cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
}
else if (w <= 1)
{
    price = 3.5 * w;
}
else if (w <= 3)
{
    price = 5.5 * w;
}
else if (w <= 10)
{
    price = 8.5 * w;
}
else if (w <= 20)
{
    price = 10.5 * w;
}
else if (w <= 30)
{
    price = 12.5 * w;
}
else
{
    cout << "The package cannot be shipped" << endl;
}

cout << "Weight : " << w << " lbs" << endl;
```